# How does spark ensure that the spark view is read only once from source in case of 2 parallel actions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Following is my code

```
Dataset data = spark.read().createview("test").cache()
CompletableFuture.allOf(supplyAsync(() -> data.count()), supplyAsync(() -> data.count()))
```

What happens when two first operations are triggered on the above dataset in parallel? Since the terminal operation will trigger the spark source read.
How does spark ensure that the dataset is not read twice from the source since there will be a sort of race conditioning happening?

Comment: Did your first command run without error?

Comment: Spark.read() is just an example of read, to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: assigning to dataset, create view and cache are not the actions that will work as you have above.  Could you give better idea on what your code might look like? Cache will store data in memory and any actions on that cached source will read from memory unless it is removed from cache.